# Crontab pattern 0 8 what means

Tags: linux, cron

I am new to crontab, can someone just tell me how often this task goes.
Thanks.

```
0 8 * * *
```

Is it every 8 minutes?

Comment: Please refer to the [cron tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for a basic understanding of the command. https://crontab.guru/ can also assist you.

Comment: found answer thanx

Answer (score 2):

It means every day at 8:00 am

You have to set

```
*/8 * * * * path to script
```

every 8 minut